# Why do I need to "repair permissions" on my Aperture library in order to migrate to Photos?

Tags: photos, permission, aperture, photos.app

After installing Apple Photos as part of the 10.10.3 update and attempting to migrate my Aperture library I get an error message about "permissions" on my Aperture library:

[image]

What does this mean and why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple often uses custom permissions to prevent users from going inside library files and deleting files that need to be in place since they are thumbnails and/or database files or referenced in database files.

Here's an official knowledge base article on the permissions required and steps to fix it.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204484

Reading your alert, the step is probably precautionary to ensure that all the files are readable and ready to transfer.

You can check the locking with Finder - select the Aperture Library and choose File -> Get Info. Observe the locked button and expand the Sharing & Permissions portion if needed. You probably need Read & Write permission on the folder and all it's contents. If you wanted to dive into terminal, I'd start at the bottom of the article and work upwards.

I would let the tool work and contact AppleCare if it reports another error or doesn't fix the permissions after one pass.

Comment: I sure hope it doesn't mess with my permissions (hands off Apple!) on [`/usr/local`](http://brew.sh)!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No - this is a very local repair process. I was so paranoid, I copied all my libraries to one external hard drive and ejected it. Then I made a time machine backup, then I let Photos have a stab. Once Photos is done, I may allow it to be the "system library" and push those changes to the iCloud.

Comment: It's not paranoia when it matches experience. Apple and Unix don't often play as well together as they should.